# Nether warts x villagers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it possible to get nether warts from a certain villager? I have already searched through all the fortresses and could find a single wart.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is impossible to get nether warts from villagers. They are only found in Nether Fortresses.

However, if you find another fortress and you find a bit, you can make a nether wart farm using soul sand and nether wart if you want more.

Answer (score 0):

No. In Java and Bedrock editions Nether fortresses are the only source.

On the other hand, I doubt you searched them -all-. There are millions of them. Either you've been unlucky and found a fortress without any Nether Wart chambers and chests with it as loot, or you failed to notice it. Sometimes finding it is quite a journey - but once you find some you can farm it on soulsand in the overworld.

[image]